# Console bar charts and division of results based on highest? | C++

Tags: c++, visual-c++

So I've been reading a C++ Primer that has all kinds of examples and test scenarios inside that are good to make sure each new chapter has been correctly learnt and that there's no other way to improve that actually coding.

The C++ Primer asked for this "Practice Problem" to be attempted and is as follows:

> 7. Write a program that provides the option of tallying up the results of a poll with 3 possible values. The first input to the program is the poll question; the next three inputs are the possible answers. The first answer is indicated by 1, the second by 2, the third by 3. The answers are tallied until a 0 is entered. The program should then show the results of the poll—try making a bar graph that shows the results properly scaled to fit on your screen no matter how many results were entered.

So I was curious as to how the author wanted me to make sure that the results fit the screen resolution regardless of "how many results were entered" and after entering the main syntax for the loops that input the data and display. I was curious what the best way to go about this and slapped together a very, VERY simple work around that'll divide by a 1:10 ratio dependant on the highest result input (up to 1000/100)

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int main()
{

    //Variable decleration 
    string Question;
    int tally1 = 0, tally2 = 0, tally3 = 0;
    int input = 1;
    int resultRatio;

    //Question input and text fluff
    cout << "Please enter a poll that has 3 answers: ";
    getline(cin, Question, '?');
    cout << "Your question is: " << Question << "?" << endl;
    cout << "When results are complete for specified poll answer, enter 0 to input results" << endl;

    while (1) //Tally 1 answer input.
    {
        cout << "Please enter the tallies for answer A: ";
        cin >> input;
        tally1 = tally1 + input;
        if (input != 0)
        {
            cout << "A's current tallies: " << tally1 << endl;
            continue;
        }
        cout << endl;
        break;
    }
    while (1) //Tally 2 answer input.
    {
        cout << "Please enter the tallies for answer B: ";
        cin >> input;
        tally2 = tally2 + input;
        if (input != 0)
        {
            cout << "B's current tallies: " << tally2 << endl;
            continue;
        }
        cout << endl;
        break;
    }
    while (1) //Tally 3 answer input.
    {
        cout << "Please enter tallies for answer C: ";
        cin >> input;
        tally3 = tally3 + input;
        if (input != 0)
        {
            cout << "C's current tallies: " << tally3 << endl;
            continue;
        }
        cout << endl;
        break;
    }

    // Ratio in which total tallies should be divded by before bar chart display
    if (tally1 >= 10 || tally2 >= 10 || tally3 >= 10)
    {
        resultRatio = 10;
    }
    else if (tally1 >= 100 || tally2 >= 100 || tally3 >= 100)
    {
        resultRatio = 100;
    }
    else if (tally1 >= 1000 || tally2 >= 1000 || tally3 >= 1000)
    {
        resultRatio = 1000;
    }
    else
    {
        resultRatio = 1;
    }

    //Simple bar chart to display all the results in a ratio that'll fit the screen thanks to resultRatio division
    cout << "All results have been entered, here is the barchart (Results displayed are divided by " << resultRatio <<"):";
    cout << endl << "A:" << "(" << tally1 << "votes )";
    for (int i = tally1 / resultRatio; i > 0; i--)
    {
        cout << "o";
    }
    cout << endl << "B:" << "(" << tally2 << "votes )";
    for (int i = tally2 / resultRatio; i > 0; i--)
    {
        cout << "o";
    }
    cout << endl << "C:" << "(" << tally3 << "votes )";
    for (int i = tally3 / resultRatio; i > 0; i--)
    {
        cout << "o";
    }
    cout << "\nHere is the full bar graph on input results";
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Please read the books chapter on "functions" (I'm sure it must have one).

Comment: Unfortunately that's not part of C++, you have to figure out some platform-specific way to get the dimensions of the console window. There are plenty of tutorials, examples, and references out there if you just search a little.

Comment: @JesperJuhl I haven't actually gotten to functions yet in the book, I understand their role however i'm trying to learn everything from scratch so why would the author expect me to implement something I haven't even yet been taught? Edit: Well the next chapter is "functions" now I really feel like it was a primer...

Comment: About the problem, it doesn't sound like anything from  [the C++ Primer book](https://www.amazon.com/gp/product/0321714113/ref=dbs_a_def_rwt_bibl_vppi_i0). And after a little searching it's really from a different book, called [Jumping Into C++](https://www.amazon.com/Jumping-into-C-Alex-Allain/dp/0988927802). Not having read that book, are you sure there isn't anything mentioned about how to get the console dimensions or how to solve your problem? Perhaps it's expected that you do that research yourself?

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude Yeah when I stated that I've been "reading *a* C++ primer" which was in fact "Jumping into C++" the book doesn't expect you to know this and by doing research and asking questions, I came across functions which is conveniently mentioned in the next Chapter of the book so props to the author for that forward thinking!